# Alinhar rodapé de uma div, com o rodapé de outra div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Bom galera, estou fazendo um projeto web, utilizando bootstrap. Gostaria de saber o seguinte:

Tenho uma div, onde a quantidade de elementos dentro dela (inputs) é menor do que uma segunda div, do seu lado (ambas com col-md-6 dentro de uma row). A imagem abaixo ilustra a situação.

[image: Resultado inicial]

O que eu gostaria, é saber como posso alinhar a div da esquerda, com o rodapé da div da direita, sem ter que fixar o tamanho das divs (pois pode haver necessidade de incluir mais campos. A imagem abaixo ilustra o resultado esperado.

[image: Resultado esperado]

Detalhe: Não existe CSS customizado nestas boxes, somente utilizando os Grids e alinhamentos do próprio bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz da seguinte forma, meio braçal mas resolveu o problema. Quem puder complementar a resposta com um meio de fazer via CSS agradeço.

$('#box-esquerda').height($('#box-direita').height());